# Xslt for each with xpath and condition

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

I have a xslt template and a xml document like below:

Normally any data inside xml is exported like this:

```
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">sss</Data></Cell>
```

I want to make some change inside xslt that: if any value inside record object contains `<br/>`, it should export data like this:

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">sss</Data></Cell>
```

Can anyone help me about that?

Xslt template:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"> 

<xsl:template match="/">
  <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <Styles>
      <Style ss:ID="s62">
        <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
      </Style>
    </Styles>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Workbook>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="/*">
  <Worksheet>
  <xsl:attribute name="ss:Name">
  <xsl:value-of select="local-name(/*/*)" />
  </xsl:attribute>
    <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
      <Row>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[position() = 1]/*">
          <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">
          <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
          </Data></Cell>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Row>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <Row>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Row>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
  <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </Data></Cell>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Xml document:

```
<records>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-02T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-02T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>1620.88</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>1535.56</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-25T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-25T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>641.46</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>615.79</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-19T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-19T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>sss</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>829.58</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-10-26T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-10-26T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>26.25</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>25</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-29T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-29T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>101000018058934</CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>284.68</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>254.62</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-02T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-02T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>101000018058937</CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>464.67</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>415.31</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-21T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-21T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>2468.4</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>2355.32</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-05T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-05T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>101000018058931</CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>281.53</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>251.8</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-11T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-11T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>101000018058940</CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>284.68</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>254.62</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-24T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-24T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>101000018058944</CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>281.53</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>251.8</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-09T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-09T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>1129.6</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>1072.17</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-28T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-28T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>0</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>0</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-10T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-10T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>354.76</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>354.76</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-22T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-22T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>2926.57</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>2789.97</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-29T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-29T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>2531.84</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>2414.73</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-30T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-30T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>101000018058932</CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>281.53</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>251.8</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-30T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-30T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>101000018106146</CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>453.55</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>405.39</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-10T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-10T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>101000018058938</CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>0</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>0</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-16T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-16T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>4912.66</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>4655.07</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-13T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-13T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>2313.17</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>2211.51</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-14T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-14T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>4061.73</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>3867.42</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-23T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-23T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>101000018166873</CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>257.79</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>230.61</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-25T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-25T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>101000018097884</CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>547.61</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>489.37</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-07T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-07T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>101000018058926</CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>346.04</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>309.4</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-10-30T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-02-07T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>-146.38</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>-139.41</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-03T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-03T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>1143.59</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>1089.13</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-05T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-05T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>2658.48</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>2531.88</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-24T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-24T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>2331.96</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>2231.19</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-17T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-17T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>161.43</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>161.43</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-27T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-27T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>759.56</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>759.56</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-08T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-08T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>172.23</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>161.64</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-12T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-12T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>1073.5</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>1019.13</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-06T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-06T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>2846.11</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>2712.64</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-23T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-23T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>8747.19</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>8335.29</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-04T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-04T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>826.45</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>798.53</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-01T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-01T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>2061.93</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>1967.81</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-18T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-18T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>2580.77</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>2453.35</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-30T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-30T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>729.09</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>705.05</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-15T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-15T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>1862.96</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>1772.08</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-14T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-14T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>101000018058939</CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>281.53</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>251.8</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-03T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-03T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>101000018058942</CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>431.24</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>385.48</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-26T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-26T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>585.76</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>558.39</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-07T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-07T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>1162.81</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>1105.44</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-24T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-24T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>101000018058929</CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO>
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>281.53</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>251.8</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
<record>
    <BASLAMA_TARIH>2012-11-11T00:00:00</BASLAMA_TARIH>
    <BITIS_TARIH>2013-11-11T00:00:00</BITIS_TARIH>
    <CF_ONCEKI_POLICE_NO />
    <CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>2004.01</CF_SUM_BRUT_PRIM>
    <CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>1908.58</CF_SUM_NET_PRIM>
</record>
```

Comment: You example XML does not contain any <br/> element. Can you give a short example with proper input and desired output? Also, you should have a look at some XSLT fundamentals (recently suggested on another question: http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTutorial/Output/). You should probably make an identity transform the starting point of your transformation.

Comment: I thinked you can imagine that this data has <br/> element. I'm looking xslt document for almost 6 hours, but i couldn't handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
  <Cell>
    <xsl:if test=".//br">
      <xsl:attribute name="ss:StyleID">s62</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of select="." /></Data>
  </Cell>
</xsl:template>
```

adding the `ss:StyleID` attribute conditionally based on the presence/absence of descendant `<br>` elements.  However the `<br>` will not appear in the generated `<Data>` element because you're using `<xsl:value-of>` (which just gives you a plain text string value).  You might want to use `<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>` instead, which will preserve the element structure of the children.

Comment: Your template is working great. I just changed <br/> with New line char. So I have a last question. what should I write instead of test=".//br" code to find new line?

Comment: @mavera: I would try `test="contains(., '&#10;')"`.